# Is there an equivalent word for '3/4?'

Tags: terminology, fractions

It's already known that the most of the quarter fractions have a single word equivalent that correspond with its numerical counterpart, such as '1/4' is a quarter, '1/2' is half, and '4/4' is the same as a whole. I want to know is there an equivalent single word for '3/4' without reading it as 'three-fourths' or 'three-quarters?' I don't know for which community this should be posted under, so correct me to suggest otherwise.

Comment: you can say "three quaters" but that's not a single word.

Comment: This question *may* be appropriate for the English Languagee SE. But I don't this this is a very good question here or there. What's wrong with just using the word *three-quarters*?

Comment: I believe some languages have a word for 2/3.  But not English.

Comment: Most of the quarter fractions have a single word because they are also *one* of something: one quarter, one half, one whole.  Three quarters is not *one* of anything in the same way.

Comment: I was surprised to learn, while looking in to this, that other languages do have words for fractions that aren't reducible to "one over" something.

Comment: @MikePierce It's primarily out of curiosity. As I have said in my question, all of those fractions that were mentioned have a single word equivalent except for 3/4, which is a compound word. Another reason why I asked that, the word 'three-quarters' seems kind of cumbersome in comparison. There's really not much wrong with using 'three-quarters.'

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there is a single *correct* answer to your question, so instead here is a list of possibilities.

- triquarter
- triplequarter
- subquarter
- shortquarter
- quartershort
- pacman $\bbox[5ex]{} $[image]

Comment: Although the 'pacman' is not as old as the word 'half', it's a nice suggestion though.

Comment: Since @Joffan added *pacman*, I'm now seriously doubting my claim that there is no single correct answer. :)

Comment: I was quite pleased with it :-)

Comment: I literally call it pacman now, this should become an official naming of 3/4